# UI shows special characters, but not explorer (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-explorer, desktop, characters

In short, I had W10 v1511, no problem. I did a fresh install of W10 RS5 of october.

And now, special characters on desktop and explorer are not properly displayed. I see a rectangle instead. But the weird thing is, when I copy/paste one in a "system window", it is rendered.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnVEO.png)

What's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug that is present only in both versions of redstone 5 (1809).

Redstone 4 is ok.